# How to disable selected button hover in java-fx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to make selected button look completely like unselected. All I need is to be able to check whether button was clicked or not. I have tried almost everything but still can't do what I want. Now I have this css. If button is selected its
lower border becomes thicker than others. Is there any possibility to get rid of that, so all the borders of selected button will be the same size?

```
.button {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}

.button:focused {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

This is how it looks like
[image: what it looks like (all grid cells without letters are buttons)]

Comment: I have used `-fx-focus-traversable: false;`for this. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Axel yeah, it works perfectly. Thank you!